# Get complete word after matching the pattern in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

```
var myVar= $("[class*=TextType]").attr("class")

//myVar returns Textabc Textxyz TextTypeTestingText
//I want to get TextTypeTestingText from myVar

var FinalWord = myVar.match(/TextType+/g)

alert(FinalWord)
```

This only alerts TextType but not the whole word that I am looking for

Comment: `var FinalWord = myVar.match(/\bTextType\w*/)`

Comment: shouldn't `myVar` have the whole class because of `.attr('class')`?

Comment: Gives me undefined. Does not work

Comment: @LearnAspNet It works here: https://jsfiddle.net/6ww7mjqs/  So you are obviously doing something else wrong

Comment: @LearnAspNet: Another way - [`var FinalWord = myVar.substring(myVar.lastIndexOf(' ')+1)`](https://jsfiddle.net/6ww7mjqs/1/).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew In this case, looks more readable imho: `myVar.split(' ').pop()`

Comment: That's why I am not posting: this not readable, that is less efficient, less compatible...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew:- It works, thanks

Comment: A lot of approaches will work here, you just need basic knowledge of string methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to match only letters, not to repeat the last character (in your case `e`).

```
'Textabc Textxyz TextTypeTestingText'.match(/TextType\w*/)[0]; // TextTypeTestingText
```

If you want to match other non-space characters too, you can use `/TextType\S+/`.